# Heroku command not found in Windows 10

Tags: python, facebook, heroku, npm, chatbot

I want to make a Python chat bot following [this article](https://blog.hartleybrody.com/fb-messenger-bot/).

But after installing the heroku-cli through npm or Windows 32 bit version or Windows 64 bit version, I am getting the following error:

> 'heroku' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

It automatically set the Path as follows when installing:

[image: environment variables]

Answer (score 8):

Restart your machine or restart all the processes that needed access to that variable(e.g vs code, cmd or file explorer).
This happens a lot on windows after adding a directory to the PATH variable. Running processes do not receive changes made to environment variables.

Comment: Thank you! I spent 3-4 hours to understand what the issue was. )

Answer (score 2):

While adding `PATH` variable do check which `PATH` you are adding to. There are two boxes:  `User Variables for administrator` or `System Variables`.

[image]

If it is the top one in the image, it will work in command prompt when run only as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting my machine worked for me! Solved the issue.

```
heroku -v
```

now works.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to restart you code editor to fix this issue.
After run the command again.

Comment: Is it because the application/shell has to be restarted before the path change takes effect?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `npm uninstall -g heroku` and installing it again did not work.

Even setting the path variable manually failed. So i deleted everything about heroku and installed the Heroku CLI installer from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

It automatically made the path and installed all heroku files to the Program Files folder.
After that I tried in my root project folder with Git Bash $`heroku login` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me this command from command prompt worked.

```
npm install -g heroku
```

And then typing

```
heroku login
```

worked.